# Can I use a laptop microphone and webcam for an application on a desktop?

Tags: laptop, audio, webcam, desktop-computer, microphone

I game on a desktop computer and I have a few spare laptops. I use one next to my gaming desktop to manage Skype, etc., but I want to use the microphone and perhaps the webcam in game.

Is there any way I can use my laptop microphone and webcam for applications on my desktop?

Comment: There might be, but I'm pretty sure it'd be better to just buy a cheap webcam with a built-in microphone.

Comment: @Alex Perhaps is there a way in which I could take the hardware from my laptop which I could take apart, and import the hardware into the desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a Mac or any Apple product to use line in. Line in is a noun.

1. Take an AUX cord and plug it into your audio out/headphone jack on the laptop.
2. Hook that to your Desktops Mic or line in ports (a lot of the time they are one and the same).
3. On your laptop  go to your `Audio device settings > Recording devices > [your audio driver]`.
4. In the Properties you will find an option to "Listen to this device", choose that (it makes it so what is picked up from your laptop's mic will play over the laptop speakers/headset.

Be careful where you laptop is in comparison to your desktop, it can very easily create an audio loop and lots of feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mac OS X, you can use [LineIn](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11333/linein) to route the microphone input to your headphone jack. You could then have a cable going from the headphone jack on your laptop to the input jack on your desktop.

Comment: Any solution for Windows 8?

Comment: @Anton8000 [This might work](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm), but unfortunately it isn't free.